# Maintaining several constants for several bash scripts

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have several individual bash scripts. They do different things, and are large (70-100 lines each). Thus I have kept them in separate files. But they are all related to a central problem and hence share several constant values in common.

So, for simplicity, I have ten constant variables, some are strings, some are numbers, while two are arrays, all of which need to be available throughout ten different bash scripts. How do I achieve this?

Note that while there is a central `main.sh` which can call these individual bash scripts, this won't always be the case. They can also be called directly from the command line (`./script1.sh`). Even in that case the variables should be made available to the scripts.

The only way I thought of was that to code in `dev/script1.temp.sh` files, and every time I need to run any file, I run a `build.sh` bash script that simply replaced (via `grep`) all occurrences of a particular constant (`$CONSTANT`) throughout the file to produce `build/script1.sh`.

Comment: You could either set them as environment variables so they are the same across every executed script, or keep them all in a file which you parse during the start of every script. Which solution do you prefer? I'd suggest environment variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put all the constants in a file, `constants.env` for example. And in all the scripts using any of those constants, put `. constants.env` to load them.

For example, `constants.env`:

```bsh
HELLO=world
```

`script.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
. constants.env
echo $HELLO
```

Executing the example:

```
$ ./script.sh 
world
```